# peugeot 207 cc depollution system faulty when roof down

Tags: cel, peugeot, misfire

My wife's peugeot 207 cc is showing "depollution system faulty" and the engine management light comes on but this only when the roof down,  also seems to be missing on a cylinder ????

I also borrowed a code reader from a work mate after the first time this happened (by this time the engine management light had gone off) and it gave a P1337 as the fault code when the roof is down.  There is a noticeable loss of power which makes me think there is a misfire

The car is 2009 16 16v 120bhp

Comment: Is there any additional information you can provide?  Year of the car is important.  Why do you think it's misfiring on a cylinder?   The information on why you think it's misfiring is relevant information to add to your question.  Thanks.

Comment: Which *exact* OBDII codes are given by the vehicle computer when this happens?

Comment: Hi i borrowed a code reader from a work mate after the first time this happened (by this time the engine management light had gone off) and it gave p1337 as the fault code  when the roof is down there is a noticeable loss of power which makes me think there is a misfire  the is 2009 16 16v 120bhp

Comment: p1337 although the engine management light had gone off by itself when i had use of the code reader

Comment: When you say the light comes on when the roof is down, do you mean it comes on when DRIVING with the roof down, or do you mean the error appears as soon as you take the roof down? If the former it could be a marginal component that's failing due to additional drag from driving with the top down. If the latter, it could be a wiring problem.

Comment: Hi yes it happened while driving on both occasions,  I think the issue may be sorted I have replaced the spark plugs and this seems to have solved the problem,  thank you for your time and help